# GIT_WORK_TREE is not working as expected

Tags: git

I used this [link](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto) to setup git bare repo and try to have the files in web server.
I wrote this line in `hooks/post-receive` file to update files in web server

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/www.example.org git checkout -f
```

After I push the code to bare repo, I don't see files in `var/www/www.example.org` what would be the problem?

**update:**
my files are in `staging` branch not in `master`. so should I do use `staging` in `checkout`

Answer (score 1):

You should create directory before.

```
mkdir /var/www/www.example.org
```

And makesure `git` user have accress to this dir.

```
sudo chown git. /var/www/www.example.org
sudo -u git -H chmod 755 /var/www/www.example.org
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `post-receive` hook is actually being executed. You can add a `echo` command if you want.

The `#!/bin/sh` is necessary in many cases and also make sure you have marked the hook as executable.

Comment: I tried `echo "1"` then I see `remote:1` when I do push from local machine. `#!/bin/sh` is also there in `post-receive` file. I don't see files in `/var/www/www.example.org` folder.

Comment: how do I check whether hook is executable?

Comment: @niren - If you are seeing the output from it, it is already executable.